# return value not as expected, MIN , compiler issue, numerical overflow?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, overflow, min

the following line code is present (embedded programming, C language, Code Composer Studio compiler):

```
bs[Line] = (21.0F - ( (13.5F / 0.035F) * (MIN( abs_yaw, 0.06F) - 0.025F) ) );
```

where

```
#define MIN(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

21.0F is the result in a local variable,

other values in the line above are really constants.

For an abs_yaw just above 0.025 (and we know it is) we should get a bs close to abs.
However, we receive a bs equal to -341.9...

any ideas why this can happen?

Comment: Please post more code. specifically, what value you are actually using for abs_yaw, and what data type bs[Line] is, such as float, double, etc.

Comment: Possibility 1: the local variable does not in fact contain 21.0f. Possibility 2: `abs_yaw` is not a variable, but an expression with side effects. Possibility 3: You do **not** know that `abs_yaw` is just above 0.025, it's in fact larger.

Comment: @DanielFischer indeed, with more code we could help better.

Comment: I agree with @DanielFischer, and add that the "wrong" value makes me suspicious. Instead of around 19-20 degrees (the correct value), it gives -341.9, *which is one full circle minus those same 19-20 degrees, as if it was a yaw correction gone awry...*.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        float abs_yaw = 0.022 + (i / 4000.0);
        float result = (21.0F - ((13.5F / 0.035F) * (MIN(abs_yaw, 0.06F) - 0.025F)));
        printf("%2d: %6.4f yields %10.6f\n", i, abs_yaw, result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces these results with GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.4.

```
 0: 0.0220 yields  22.157143
 1: 0.0223 yields  22.060715
 2: 0.0225 yields  21.964285
 3: 0.0227 yields  21.867857
 4: 0.0230 yields  21.771429
 5: 0.0233 yields  21.674999
 6: 0.0235 yields  21.578571
 7: 0.0237 yields  21.482143
 8: 0.0240 yields  21.385714
 9: 0.0243 yields  21.289286
10: 0.0245 yields  21.192858
11: 0.0247 yields  21.096428
12: 0.0250 yields  21.000000
13: 0.0253 yields  20.903572
14: 0.0255 yields  20.807142
15: 0.0258 yields  20.710714
16: 0.0260 yields  20.614286
17: 0.0262 yields  20.517859
18: 0.0265 yields  20.421429
19: 0.0268 yields  20.325001
```

You can adapt it to hone in on your values, but it doesn't look like there should be a problem, and you may, conceivably, have found a compiler bug.  OTOH, your test code probably isn't as simple as this; if you try this, it will probably work.  So, don't go claiming compiler bug yet.  Assume there is a fault in your code until all else fails.  Try a different compiler (get a second opinion on the same code).

Comment: since he's programming embedded, and doesn't specify the processor type or precision of variables, for all we know it could be trapping denormals on 16-bit floats and flushing to 0, or substituting fixed-point math. A different compiler won't necessarily help this problem if it isn't available. OP doesn't really specify.

Comment: All valid points, but this is indicative of a way to debug the problem.  There might not be `printf()` either, and maybe no way to display on the embedded device.  Maybe there's an emulator.  But there'd have to be a lot of evidence to convince me that the problem is in the compiler and not in the code...and a test case like this would help a lot.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave Not to be politically correct, but the OP's name indicates it's a she.

Answer (score 0):

> any ideas why this can happen?

Yes: in your code you have a check for the case when yaw angle crosses a full circle to trigger sign inversion, and that code gets executed due to some *other* error (possibly 0.025 is a guard margin used elsewhere?).

As a result, instead of 20 degrees or so, you get 360°-20°, and that's where that -341 value is coming from.

Of course, without seeing the code, this is just a guess. And a memory of my own past mistakes.

Comment: If this were a gambling site, I would up-vote this answer. But there's not enough info in the OP.